# (Resolved in Step 3) CoreBluetooth: When I pass CBUUID as array to scanForPeripherals withServices nothing happened. (Xcode 12.5, Swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

When I pass `CBUUID` as array to `scanForPeripherals` `withServices` nothing happened. (Xcode 12.5, Swift 5)

**Step 1**. Getting all devices near me and getting identifiers:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//

import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    private var centralManager : CBCentralManager!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: nil)
    }
    
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == .poweredOn {
            centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices:nil, options: nil)
        }
    }
    
    public func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        
        guard let name = peripheral.name else { return }
        
        print("\nName   : \(name)")
        print(peripheral.identifier)// Getting identifier here.(9SD480E0-4362-4412-6350-D143DC3D14BE)
       
    }

}
```

**Step 2**. (WRONG) Calling with identifiers and nothing is being discovered:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//

import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    private var centralManager : CBCentralManager!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: nil)
    }
    
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == .poweredOn {
             centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [CBUUID.init(string: "9SD480E0-4362-4412-6350-D143DC3D14BE")], options: nil)
        }
    }
    
    public func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        
        // NOTHING IS BEING DISCOVERED
       
    }

}
```

**Step 3**. The correct path to follow is Step 1 (for getting id's) and Step 3 (to retrieve peripherals). Thank you @Paulw11:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//

import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    private var centralManager : CBCentralManager!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: nil)
    }
    
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == .poweredOn {
            
            guard let uuid = UUID(uuidString: "9SD480E0-4362-4412-6350-D143DC3D14BE") else { return }
            let result = centralManager.retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers: [uuid])
            print(result) // CBPeripheral
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't scan for peripheral `identifiers` you scan for the service UUID you are interested in. Having discovered a peripheral you can store its `identifier` and use that later with `retrievePeripherals(with identifiers)` rather than having to scan in the future.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you for your answer! In what protocol's method it is fall after `retrievePeripherals(with identifiers)`?

Comment: I got it! I looked into docs! It is returning a collection of [CBPeripheral]! Thank you @Paulw11 again!